# Impresión de esquinas de una matriz en JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un ejercicio que me indica lo siguiente, crear una función que reciba una matriz, este método dará como retorno una matriz con las esquinas de la matriz original. Ambas matrices se deben imprimir posteriormente, y que se indique la original y la del resultado.

Esto es lo que llevo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] matriz = {{9, 8, 7}, {6, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}};

    System.err.println("Impresión de matriz original");
    impresionMatriz(matriz);

    System.err.println(" Impresión de las esquinas");
    mutiplicarLasEsquinas(matriz);

}


public static void impresionMatriz(int[][] matriz) {

    System.out.println("--------------- Impresión de Matriz --------------------");
    for (int x = 0; x < matriz.length; x++) {
        System.out.print("|");
        for (int y = 0; y < matriz[x].length; y++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[x][y]);
            if (y != matriz[x].length - 1) {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }



  public static void imprimirEsquinas(int [][]){

   } 

}
```

Si me pudieran colaborar estaría más que agradecido.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta, en tu ejemplo, que número se deberían multiplicar con cuales?

Comment: Mira, debería entonces multiplicar la operación que en este caso sería: el 9 * 3 * 7 * 1

Comment: Por qué 7 * 3, entonces el array del medio no sirve? sé lo más específico que puedas, edita la pregunta y agrega más detalles

Comment: Segun entiendo tiene que multiplicarlo haciendo forma de "Z"

Comment: Ya, hice las modificaciones adecuadas, disculpen por las molestias causadas.

Comment: es muy fácil obtener las esquinas, si analizas una matriz de tamaño nxn sus esquinas son: [0,0], [0,n], [n,0], [n,n]. y ya el problema es más conceptual que nada.

Comment: ¿Y en código cómo podría ser el método?